# How to open a url on a new Chrome Tab using selenium C# over NUnit test framework

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, nunit

I am trying to test a single sign-on feature; wherein I opened a chrome session and logged onto a webpage. Thereafter I want to open a new tab on the same browser window and open another extension of previously entered url to verify it retains user session. I can't get to open a new tab on chrome and then switch focus --

This is what I have tried (I am new to this, still learning....so thanks for all the help/suggestions)

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test
{
[Binding]
public class XXX
{
    IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); 


    public void LoginPage()
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.abcd.com/");
    }


    public void LoggedIn()
    {
        //Entering username & password on Platform login page
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("username")).SendKeys("abcd");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("password")).SendKeys("XXXX");

        var loginBtn = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[type='button']"));
        loginBtn.Click();

    }


    public void OpenANewBrowserTab()
    {
        driver.SwitchTo().ParentFrame();


driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body")).SendKeys(Keys.Control + "t");
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://abcd.com/ux");

    }
```

I am getting below error --

```
An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException' occurred in 
WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: no such element: Unable to locate element: 
{"method":"css selector","selector":"body"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get focus use this statement .

```
driver.SwitchTo().ActiveElement();
```

It has same semantics of the javascript statement *document.activeElement* .If that doesn't work for you. Then as a last resort, you can always use **javascript**.

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.ExecuteScript("var win = window.open('https://www.bing.com', '_blank');
      win.focus();");
```

Comment: Done that, but still can't get to open a new tab. Getting below error --

An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"body"}

Comment: Unable to locate element: That's a locator issue. You need to look again and verify your locator. Anyways , I have edited the answer and provided another solution.

Comment: Your suggested solution works perfectly. Thanks heaps @Manmohan_singh